# What's a good library or coding approach to create an XML-like file at run time

Tags: c#

I would like to write some sort of API such that I can call it and say hey add this thing as the subclass of that thing and the output File that it generates for me I would able to see something like this:

[image]

or tell it to declare these things as a class and the output look would look like this:

[image]

In here, just those Person and Student are the params that I will pass to the API. The rest of it are like keywords, will always be the same.

Basically something like this: http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-ref/#subClassOf-def

So I am interested to know about your suggestions for what is good approcahc or Libaries, etc... that help me with this sort of file manipulation?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried searching for a library that will suit your needs? Where did you look? What have you found that came close?

Comment: And why can't you use xml?????

Comment: @TonyHopkinson : That's part of the question: Do you think using XML methods is a good option to do this or there are better ways? If yes, then like what?

Comment: It is? Of course it's a good option. It's there, it's standard and it's proven. No need to for you or anyone else to invent a subtly different flavour of mark up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use c# and use the `XmlDocument` class

Basically you specify what nodes to add to an XML document by using it's methods, then you can grab the XML output and stream it to a file etc

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx

What experience have you got with programming?

Example of usage here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw1ys7w6.aspx

I suppose it depends on what kind of control you need - this may be overkill for what you want